# Manipulate promises & hasMany arrays in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently having trouble accessing the data returned by my fixtures. They either return a promise or a hasMany array, however, even when using a .then function call I am unable to successfully retrieve data in my controller. Handlebars will render them and resolve them, but I cannot compute or modify them prior to render.

See my JSBin here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OyItix/10/edit

Can I convert them to an enumerable array?

For anyone else who find this:

```
var participants = this.get('group.participants'); // Get it from the store, returns a promise

participants.then(function(result) { 
    result.get('content').forEach( function(participant) {
        console.log(participant.get('name'));
    });
});
```

The return value for the property will initially be null, but will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need convert them.

Add argument to property() in controller (IndexController), then observation will be recalculated automatically, when model updated.

property() =>  property('group.participants')

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/axIyicu/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for the reply, if I have multiple properties from different stores that are returning promises, i.e. measures and group.participants, do I put them both in the property method of controller and it will recalculate once they've been resolved?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/axIyicu/3/edit - example where with 2 properties. observation updated when updated any property.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm looking to use the values in the controller, rather than output both Measures and Group.Participants. I'm going to use the 2 to query another store and compile observationData for that assessment. I think you've given me enough to go forward with this approach, however, I was curious if you had any suggestions for a better way to do so.

Comment: function then() work different then you expect. when you call then you add listener, you don't execute internal block; observationData return some value BEFORE function passed into 'then()' executed. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ewuXOhu/1/edit (read console output)

Comment: I see that, but doesn't it eventually resolve, even though it initially is null. Without the then it doesn't work at all:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ewuXOhu/2/edit

Comment: I've got it thanks, the issue is was push rather than pushObject method.